# Binary variable switch constraints

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, binary-variable

I have a set of binary variables $X = \{ x_1, x_2, x_3, ... x_N \}$ which are connect and used with the rest of the model.

I want to define a set of binary variables which represents the change between the variables in $X$ with adjacency. Let this set be $Y = \{ y_1._2, y_2._3, y_3._4, ... y_{N-1}._{N} \}$.

This set $Y$ is expected to behave like this,

$$y_i._{i+1} = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x_i=x_{i+1}$ } \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Eventually, I wish to limit the summation of these $y_i._{i+1}$ variables, but that is an easy part. Question is, how can I define $y_i._{i+1}$ variables in the OR model in terms of $X$ variables which reflects the multi-definition above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to enforce
$$
\lnot y_{i,i+1}\iff (x_i\iff x_{i+1}).
$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$
(\lnot y_{i,i+1} \lor \lnot x_i \lor \lnot x_{i+1})\land (\lnot y_{i,i+1} \lor x_i
\lor x_{i+1}) \land (y_{i,i+1} \lor \lnot x_i \lor x_{i+1}) \land (y_{i,i+1} \lor x_i \lor \lnot x_{i+1}),
$$
from which we obtain linear constraints
\begin{align}
(1-y_{i,i+1}) +(1-x_i)+(1-x_{i+1})&\ge1\\
(1-y_{i,i+1})+x_i+x_{i+1}&\ge 1\\
 y_{i,i+1} +(1-x_i)+x_{i+1}&\ge 1\\
y_{i,i+1} +x_i +(1-x_{i+1})&\ge 1
\end{align}
Equivalently,
\begin{align}
y_{i,i+1}+x_i+x_{i+1}&\le 2\\
-y_{i,i+1}+x_i+x_{i+1}&\ge 0\\
 y_{i,i+1} -x_i+x_{i+1}&\ge 0\\
y_{i,i+1} +x_i -x_{i+1}&\ge 0
\end{align}

Comment: Dear Dr. Pratt, as all the above model variables are binary, can we apply the usual big-M formulation to linearize such constraint? By changing the equality constraint (x=x) into two inequality (x>=x and x<=x) and adding the auxiliary binary variable for linking these constraints?

Comment: Yes, in this case, the big-M approach would yield the same set of constraints.  For example, you can view the first of the four constraints as $x_i+x_{i+1}-1\le M(1-y_{i,i+1})$, with $M=1$, which enforces $y_{i,i+1}=1\implies x_i+x_{i+1}\le 1$.

Comment: Many thanks Dr. Pratt for your hints. 